# Are multiple separate feature classes more efficient than repeatedly deleting all features from same feature class?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, performance, python-toolbox, personal-geodatabase

*Quick Version: Is it more efficient, in terms of database performance, to have multiple separate temporary feature classes or one feature class that you repeatedly empty out and fill?*

I am working with ArcGIS 10.1, Windows 7, using personal geodatabases.

I have a python toolbox tool that selects survey cells based on their proximity to a seed-cell.  Once a boundary is determined, based on distance from the last selected set of cells, the final selected set is buffered to form the boundary.  I have been using a single feature class (*BoundaryHopper*)to hold the output of the buffer and then appending that output to a second feature class that holds all the boundaries for a project (*DerivedBoundaries*).  *BoundaryHopper* would be emptied out at the beginning of each loop iteration to avoid repeatedly appending the same boundaries to *DerivedBoundaries*  ]

Recently I switched the tool over to using  separate outputs for each buffer output (*TempBoundary1,2,3...*) and appending each individual feature class to *DerivedBoundaries*.  That solved some issues I was having from trying to overwrite the same feature class all the time.

So, my question is: ***Are there any significant performance benefits of one technique over the other?*** Does one technique create less 'bloat' in the database or result in faster processing?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using .mdb and not .gdb?

Comment: .mdb because I use the tables as data sources for a mail-merge to build summary packets for each boundary.  The .gdb makes it harder to do that, so I just use the access format that is Word-friendly.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but unless you're experiencing a performance problem -- the pragmatic programmer would say you're done. Theoretically, a database table is meant to repeatedly handle repeated CRUD operations (even Access) and using temporary tables mildly violates normalization where you want to minimize redundancy -- given the caveat that a database is properly configured (particularly sizing, indexes and logs) and maintained.

Comment: At this point I'll take a pragmatic solution over an optimized one!  Thanks for the input, I hadn't thought about the normalization issue but for now, it works, I guess I'll stop trying to fix it!